# Потеря байтов при копировании большого файла

Tags: java, io

Есть текстовый файл 5 000 000 200 байт. При его копировании теряю 4-5 байтов. Вижу что теряю их на цикле while, но как их вернуть - ума не приложу. Кто чем может, помогите начинающему программисту...

```
       @Override
public long readFile(File file) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    long summa = 0L;
    while(fis.read()!=-1) {
        byte[] buffer = null;
        if(fis.available()>1300000000) {
            buffer = new byte[1300000000];
        }else {
            buffer = new byte[fis.available()];
        }
        fis.read(buffer);
        summa+=buffer.length;
        }
    return summa;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public long readFile(File file) throws IOException {
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
  long summa = 0L;
  do {
    byte[] buffer = null;
    if(fis.available()>1300000000) {
        buffer = new byte[1300000000];
    }else {
        buffer = new byte[fis.available()];
    }

    int c = fis.read(buffer);  //действительное количество байт считанных в буфер или -1 если конец файла достигнут
    summa += c == -1 ? 0 : c;
  } while (c != -1);
  return summa;
}
```

Comment: не выходим из цикла.... в нем остаемся....

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо.... код заработал.. вот окончательный вариант:

Comment: @Override
 public long readFile(File file) throws IOException {
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
  long summa = 0L;
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1000000000];
  int c=0;
  do {
    c = fis.read(buffer);
    summa += c == -1 ? 0 : c;
   }while(c!=-1);
  return summa;
 }

Answer (score 1):

Вы теряете их в конструкции `while(fis.read()!=-1)` — `read()` читает один байт, но вы его никуда не записываете, вот и теряете.

А ещё, как написал Roman C выше, результат вызова `fis.read(buffer)` надо учитывать, т.к. это количество реально прочитанных байт, которое может быть меньше длины буфера `buffer`.

Ну и я бы не рекомендовал выделять массивы такой длины (1 300 000 000), а если уж делать, то один раз до начала цикла и переиспользовать этот массив.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь...код заработал...